# Why is my images no fadding out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

I just got started with JQuery and JavaScript today, so it's possible that I'm doing something very basic wrong. Basically I have a  in the mark-up, JavaScript then defines this section height to be the viewer port height. Inside that  I have 4  each one containing one Image, I want them to fade out one after the other. Here is what I came up with, it's doing nothing and I have no clue why, I tried debugging it, but couldn’t find why as well. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong? What I'd like to accomplish is a very simple full screen slide-show, because everywhere I look for it there are just ready to use templates and I'd like to know how to code it from scratch.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="pt-br">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--CSS-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <!--END CSS-->
    <!--SCRIPT-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery/my_jquery_funcs.js"></script>
    <!--END SCRIPT-->
    <title>Patrick Oliveira</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--HERO COMECA AQUI-->
<section id="hero-slider">
    <div id="slide-1"></div>
    <div id="slide-2"></div>
    <div id="slide-3"></div>
    <div id="slide-4"></div>
</section>
<script>
    realTimeHeight();/*Atualiza em tempo real a altura do slide show*/
</script>
<!--HERO TERMINA AQUI-->
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS

```
#hero-slider{
    width: 100%;
}
#slide-1, #slide-2, #slide-3, #slide-4{
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
}
#slide-1{
    background: url("../imgs/imagem1.jpeg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#slide-2{
    background: url("../imgs/imagem2.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#slide-3{
    background: url("../imgs/imagem3.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#slide-4{
    background: url("../imgs/imagem4.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And the JavaScript

```
var i = 4;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        realTimeHeight();
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        fadeItOut("#slide-"+i);
    }, 2500);
});
function fadeItOut(objectID){
    var fadeTime = 2500; /*time to fade out*/
    $("#"+objectID).fadeOut(fadeTime);
    if(i == 1){
        i = 5;
    }
    i--;
}
function realTimeHeight(){
    var altura = $(window).height();
    $("#hero-slider").css("height",altura);
}
```

P.s: I just want to learn how to make one from scratch, after that I'll start using templates for time saving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close, just one error.

`objectID` already has the hash. Basically `'#' + objectID` returns `##slide-4`

```
$('#' + objectID).fadeOut(fadeTime);
```

Should be

```
$(objectID).fadeOut(fadeTime);
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/ra6034eo/1/))